# How can I call out a string from an object array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I have recently started some OOP in C++, and I was trying to make a small program in [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) to store arrays of information on employees through a friends function. The code is rough and could use improvements, but I'm not too proficient at it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee{
    int id;
    string names[5];
    float salary;

    public:

        friend void input();
        friend void output();
};

void input(){
    employee obj[5];
    cout << "enter employee id, name and salary\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin>>obj[i].id>>obj[i].names[i]>>obj[i].salary;
    }
}

void output(){
    employee obj[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"\nwelcome "<<obj[i].name[i]<<endl<<"your id is: "<<obj[i].id<<" and your salary is: "<<obj[i].salary<<"PKR"<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){

    input();
    output();
}
```

The particular issue is that it doesn't call out the string names for some reason, and I've tried a lot of different ways to rewrite it. Am I just approaching this wrong?

Comment: `void output(){employee obj[5];` -- What is your intention of declaring a local `obj` array?  You do the same thing with the `input` function.  Also note:  you are missing `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

`employee obj[5];` is local to each functions. You should declare that in `main()` and pass that as an argument.

```cpp
void input(employee obj[]){
    cout<<"enter employee id, name and salary\n";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cin>>obj[i].id>>obj[i].names[i]>>obj[i].salary;
    }
}
void output(employee obj[]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"\nwelcome "<<obj[i].name[i]<<endl<<"your id is: "<<obj[i].id<<" and your salary is: "<<obj[i].salary<<"PKR"<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    employee obj[5];
    input(obj);
    output(obj);
}
```

Comment: ill try that, thanks

Comment: Also, what you're doing right now is allocating 5 names for each employee, and only entering the i-th name for the i-th employee. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @JulienBERNARD Oops, that is not only strange but also dangerous being out-of-range.

Comment: @JulienBERNARD Hmmm, `names` is `string[5]`, so they aren't actually out-of-range.